# php-fpm stack smashing detected

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Привет всем периодически php-fpm процесс завершается с ошибкой Stack smashing error.

Подскажите как найти причину этого? С периодичностью раз в 10 минут, бывает раз в минуту. Бывает час-два не падает.

В /var/log/messages видно такое:

```
Oct 24 19:50:30 517560-web7 kernel: [54117491.235533] Pid 11256(php-fpm) over core_pipe_limit
Oct 24 19:50:30 517560-web7 kernel: [54117491.235655] Skipping core dump
```

В /var/log/php-fpm/error.log:

```
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "*** stack smashing detected ***: php-fpm: pool www terminated"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "======= Backtrace: ========="
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x36b4d02527]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x36b4d024f0]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool www[0x6d8a7e]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool www[0x6da315]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x36b4c1ed5d]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool www[0x422899]"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "======= Memory map: ========"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "00400000-007a5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3540127                            /usr/sbin/php-fpm"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "009a5000-009fd000 rw-p 003a5000 fd:01 3540127                            /usr/sbin/php-fpm"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "009fd000-00a19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "00dfc000-00e07000 rw-p 003fc000 fd:01 3540127                            /usr/sbin/php-fpm"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "020ae000-02396000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "02396000-023b7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "023b7000-0337f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "33e2a00000-33e2a07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19014909                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "33e2a07000-33e2c06000 ---p 00007000 fd:01 19014909                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "33e2c06000-33e2c07000 r--p 00006000 fd:01 19014909                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "33e2c07000-33e2c08000 rw-p 00007000 fd:01 19014909                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4800000-36b4820000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005490                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4a1f000-36b4a20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:01 19005490                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4a20000-36b4a21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:01 19005490                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4a21000-36b4a22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4c00000-36b4d8a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005567                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4d8a000-36b4f8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:01 19005567                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4f8a000-36b4f8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:01 19005567                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4f8e000-36b4f8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:01 19005567                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b4f8f000-36b4f94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5000000-36b5017000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005868                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5017000-36b5217000 ---p 00017000 fd:01 19005868                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5217000-36b5218000 r--p 00017000 fd:01 19005868                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5218000-36b5219000 rw-p 00018000 fd:01 19005868                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5219000-36b521d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 "
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5400000-36b5402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005645                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5402000-36b5602000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 19005645                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5602000-36b5603000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 19005645                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5603000-36b5604000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 19005645                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5800000-36b5883000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005963                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5883000-36b5a82000 ---p 00083000 fd:01 19005963                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5a82000-36b5a83000 r--p 00082000 fd:01 19005963                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5a83000-36b5a84000 rw-p 00083000 fd:01 19005963                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5c00000-36b5c15000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 19005869                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5c15000-36b5e14000 ---p 00015000 fd:01 19005869                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5e14000-36b5e15000 r--p 00014000 fd:01 19005869                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3"
[24-Oct-2016 19:50:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 11256 said into stderr: "36b5e15000-36b5e16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:01 19005869                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3"
```

Это сообщение раз в 10 длиннее.
В какую сторону копать хотя бы?

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: May  9 2014 14:00:34)

nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.4.4

uname -a
Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 11:35:41 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

*Вариант 1:* Увеличить доступное число потоков Core Dump : `#ulimit -c unlimited`

Либо, в зависимости от версии пингвина:

*Вариант 2.1:*

```
#echo kernel.core_pattern= > /etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf
#/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl
#cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Вывод cat должен быть пустой

*Вариант 2.2:*

```
#ln -s /dev/null /etc/sysctl.d/coredump.conf
#/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl
```

Дальше просто вангую:

*Вариант 3:*
Попробуйте уменьшить число воркеров nginx/apache и максимальное число дочерних процессов fpm. По идее, тоже должно помочь.

p.s. Добавьте в комментарии версии используемого окружения, чтобы не приходилось гадать. Как минимум: php, php-fpm, nginx/apache, kernel

Comment: Какой смысл понижать кол-во воркеров nginx? То что передаётся в php-fpm от nginx и ломает его, так же передастся и при меньшем кол-во воркеров nginx. Никогда не делал, но мне кажется надо как-то посмотреть какая функция или что-то ещё делает так что процесс завершается с signal 11 SIGSEGV или signal 6 SIGABRT - часто вижу. Кажется это называется Backtrace - обратная трассировка, до места, которое вызвало ошибку. Видно это слово error логе php-fpm но как проследовать к этому месту, которое вызвало ошибку? P.S. Поправил вопрос, дописал версии nginx, php-fpm, ядра.

Comment: over core_pipe_limit -- ошибка, говорит о том что, кол-во одновременных дампов сломанных процессов передающихся через pipe - '|', превысило предустановленное в ядре значение. Это не причина падения php-fpm, а интересно узнать причину по которой он падает.

Comment: Вообще, stack smashing detected - это срабатывание защиты от переполнения буфера. Попробуйте просто обновить fpm.

Comment: Какого буфера? Переполнение чем?

Comment: @MishaPolitaev какого-то. Внутри. Какой-то код вылез за пределы разрешённой ему памяти. Это деталь реализации, которую из PHP-кода не починить, разве что понять чем она вызвана и обойти. Обычно это из-за бага в исполняющей среде. Так что попробуйте обновиться. Если баг достаточно серьёзный, можно ожидать, что его уже починили. А если нет, надо зарепортить или бампнуть существующий рапорт.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Переполнение_буфера

Comment: Согласен, обновится должно помочь. Но интересно узнать что вызывает срабатывание защиты от переполнения буфера. Можно как-то используя дамп упавшего php-fpm понять как функция(?) вызвала это? Зачем-то же этот backtrace делается?

Comment: Если хотите узнать что вызвало переполнение - почитайте changelog php-fpm от вашей версии до текущей. Там скорее всего будет указано. В разделе "Bugfixes"

Comment: Не, переполнение же вызывают какие-то мои входящие данные, индивидуальные. Откуда в changeloge они будут? Может там у меня что-то больше приходит в аргументах функции, я не знаю, вот это интересно узнать. Увидеть эту ошибку в backtrace.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev Когда у меня вешался интерпретатор Ruby, я подсоединялся к нему с помощью GDB и сишными функциями разбирался, в каких строчках каких файлов находятся его потоки. Наверное, то же самое можно проделать и с PHP-FPM, но в вашем случае надо поймать состояние *прямо перед падением*. Для этого нужно установить, какой запрос к вебсерверу вызывает stack smash. С этого и стоит начать, это уже может быть непросто.

Comment: А разве в backtrace, который сохраняется, не будет обращение к какой функции или файлу вызвало падение? Как его открыть, прочесть?

Comment: Backtrace - это то что вы опубликовали в вопросе. Переполнение произошло в модуле /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: @MishaPolitaev это бэктрейс процесса. Он покажет максимум где он был в коде интерпретатора, но вам эта информация ничем особо не поможет.

Comment: Ясно, ладно, попытаюсь найти запрос который вызывает падение. Благодарю за ответы!)